# How to pull init configuration and updated code in IOS application from backend server?

Tags: ios, backend, init

I am a new IOS developer. When designing the application, i figured that it will be probably wise to pull most of the configuration from the back-end server upon app init. In addition, i was thinking that instead of constantly upgrading the application (a hassle for users and developers) i might insert some way to update my code also on the system init.

my question - Is this approach do able? common? are there good practices for doing it (or best practices for that matter)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First welcome to ios programming

It is not a good practice to do so, and as far as I know it's not possible to change the code of your app after it's send to the appstore review team.

Before including your app in the appstore, Apple will create an executable file of your app which's code can't be changed.

You can use a backend service to provide different configuration options, example: you develop a chat on the app, but you want it to be shown when you change some config file on the server, so a web request to your server can be made to determine the content of the file and if has changed you could use a simple .hidden = false to unlock your chat feature

Hope it helps

Comment: What about assets? can I get assets on init in order to for example, change the button look, etc.?

Comment: @Alon1980 you may use some images, but remember it's not cool for a client to wait for images to download

Comment: if i Init my assets on the loading of the app it can be almost seamlessly.